# Using C# to INSERT INTO SQL gives Error

Tags: c#, sql

I don't understand. One of the template pages in Webmatrix (C#) has a line of code that reads:

```
// Check if user already exists
var user = db.QuerySingle("SELECT Email FROM UserProfile WHERE LOWER(Email) = LOWER(@0)", email);

if (user == null) {
    // Insert email into the profile table
    db.Execute("INSERT INTO UserProfile (Email) VALUES (@0)", email);
}
```

So in my page I'm looking for similar results. If a requested row in SQL database isn't in database, execute SQL command, to create/insert row, with value (however, there's a foreign key attached to the ID, and it's preventing my from inserting in the ID column)

```
foreach (var item in Request.Form.AllKeys)
{
    var selectQueryString = "SELECT * FROM Results WHERE ResultsId = @0";
    var row = db.QuerySingle(selectQueryString, item);

    if (row.ResultsId == null) {
        while (row.ResultsId != item)
        {
            db.Execute("INSERT INTO Results( ResultsA, ResultsB, ResultsC, ResultsD, ResultsE) values '0', '0', '0', '0', '0'");}
        }
    }
}
```

Each time I run my page, I get a runtime error

> Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference

and it points to the line:

```
if (row.ResultsId == null) {
```

I'm having a difficult time understand what I'm doing wrong.

So far, I have 2 items in database. When my page performs `(isPost)` command, the first row, is processed fine, and then I get an error before it I could ask it to make a record for the row that's not in database, and I get the above error.

I would manually add the rows into my SQL to avoid this kind of hassle, but I would like to understand this issue first, in case I decide to make a decision between the two in the future.

Oh! The database I'm inserting into has a foreign key on the column `ResultsId`.

Comment: Your code assumes that the variable `row` is not null. Are you sure that `var row = db.QuerySingle(selectQueryString, item);` returns data in every use case?

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. That was actually the issue. Although the same response was already shared, thanks for explaining it from a different angle. I understand more now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the `db.QuerySingle` method returns no results, `row` will be null, hence the attempt to bind `ResultsId` (`row.ResultsId`) becomes an attempt to bind through a null, which is an obvious non-starter. Note the original example tests for null against `user`, not `user.someproperty`

On that basis, as a start, I'd suggest changing this chunk:

```
    if(row.ResultsId == null){
```

to

```
    if(row == null){
```

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, now that i stare at it again. So, may i ask for an advice to remedy a fix? At the moment, i still trying to wrap my head around getting it to check that `item` and `row` equal the same value.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this to check the item against the row?

```
if(row != null){
      if(row.ResultsID == item){
          //fields are equal
      }
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, David, below answer was similar to the direction i was heading in. I wanted it to add rows into database when a row was missing, so i had it look for null values. Now i'm just doing a bunch of error checks till i need to manipulate the code again. Thanks for submitting